# Can I install OS X in VMware Workstation 12 from a dmg image?

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, dmg-image

I'd like to know if it's possible to mount **OS X** (10.10.x or 10.11) on a Virtual Machine under **VMWare Workstation 12 Pro** from the original **dmg** image?

If it is possible:

1. What is the process for installation?
2. What is the right configuration of the machine?

If it is not possible:

1. How do I mount OS X on a virtual machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to edit your post.

1. VMware W/S is a Windows product, not OSX. VMware Fusion is the OSX version.
2. OSX can only run reliably (with the exception of Hackintosh) on Apple h/w.
3. If you have an OSX host running Fusion, just accept the defaults and use your OSX DMG. Fusion will mount and auto setup the guest OS